# What does it mean by rebinding a string object raising an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From Python in a Nutshell

> String  objects  (byte  strings,  as  well  as  text,  AKA  Unicode, 
>   ones)  are  immutable: attempting to **rebind** or delete an item or
>   slice of a string raises an exception.

What does it mean by rebinding a string object raising an exception?

```
>>> a="hello"
>>> a="world"
>>>
```

Did I just successfully rebind variable `a` from string object `'hello'` to `'world'`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did was delete the "hello" string object and replace it with the "world" string object. The documentation means something like this:

```
>>> a="hello"
>>> a[3]="t" # does not produce helto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't "rebind" mean rebinding a variable `a` to a different string object?

Comment: @Tim in the context of your quote they're talking about rebinding an *item* (character) or *slice*, not the entire string.

Comment: @MarkRansom  How does immutability of a string imply immutability of its item or slice? For example, in C, a string literal is immutable, but we can change the values of its items.

Comment: @Tim changing the characters in a string literal in C is undefined behavior, but lets ignore that for the moment - strings in C and Python operate entirely differently. Think of variables in Python as pointers, when you assign a new string to a variable you're not changing the characters of the string you're changing the pointer to point at a different string.